# Canvas перемещение объекта по оси x

Tags: javascript, анимация, canvas

Есть объект он автоматически перемещается с помощью

```
if(object.x < 200) {
  object.x += object.speed;
}
```

после того как условие станет ложным мне нужно уменьшать позицию x
Да, я могу написать else и уменьшать значение, но если уменьшить даже на 1, он снова начнет увеличиваться т.к значение уже будет < 200
Как мне можно уменьшать позицию x до нуля после выполнения первого условия?
т.е должно получится "туда - сюда"

Comment: менять знак скорости на противоположный

Comment: в else? нет так не сработает. Я уже уточнил в самом вопросе это.

Comment: `object.x += object.x < 200 ? object.speed : -object.x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я писал в комментах вот про это:

```js
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let speed = 2;
let x = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(upd);

function upd(t) {

  // если координата x по модулю больше +-100 (всего длина 200)
  if (Math.abs(x-100) > 100) {

    // вычисляем новое направление: 
    //  берем скорость по модулю и умножаем на обратный знак текущей координаты
    speed = - Math.sign(x-100) * Math.abs(speed);
  }
  x += speed;
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150)
  ctx.fillRect(x,0,10,10 + 5*Math.sin(t/200));
  requestAnimationFrame(upd);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=canvas></canvas>
```

Откуда взялось `-100`?

я его добавляю чтобы сдвинуть все происходящее центром в начало координат.

Без этих `-100` координата `х` будет изменятся в интервале от `-100` до `+100`

Это нужно, чтобы делать только один `if` а не два, как бы 
было с оригинальными координатами `0` и `200`, `-100` переносит картину 
мира к началу координат, вот и весь фокус